# Java Android FCM sending message to user Server returned HTTP response code

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I did this :

```
public class PushNotifictionHelper {
    public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM = "AIzaSyD63pfTvnwhe9WVuIe.........";
    public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

    public static String sendPushNotification(String deviceToken)
            throws IOException, JSONException {
        String result = "";
        URL url = new URL(API_URL_FCM);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + AUTH_KEY_FCM);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        json.put("to", deviceToken.trim());
        JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
        info.put("title", "notification title"); // Notification title
        info.put("body", "message body"); // Notification
        // body
        json.put("notification", info);
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(json.toString());
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            result = "OK";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "BAD";
        }
        System.out.println("GCM Notification is sent successfully");

        return result;

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        try {
            PushNotifictionHelper.sendPushNotification("ep51x3Ckmig:APA91bG4PdoJC7zGlV0JPmCA49jmqJCkeSPH1QzF9byxdH1nRlFOVyAi9ppO2ygoSpp8s44o1oGO8n-HCJDB_oZAZ6WCwFD2a9yAFmKIpKhmPXakeLf-ktqPnzwf-GFziv7_nMdVPIci");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run this in console I see

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

an AUTH_KEY_FCM I get from web from this:

```
Klucz interfejsu Web API AIzaSyD63pfTvnwhe9WVuIe.........
```

Comment: Not a good idea to expose such authentication keys in public.

Comment: @fluffyBatman Ok thanks for advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 401 error refers to an Authentication error. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes):

> The sender account used to send a message couldn't be authenticated. Possible causes are:
>
> - Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax in HTTP request.
> - Invalid project number sent as key.
> - Key valid but with FCM service disabled.
> - Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server key IPs.
>
> Check that the token you're sending inside the Authentication header is the correct Server key associated with your project. See [Checking the validity of a Server key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#checkAPIkey) for details.

When using FCM, you should always make use of the ***Server Key*** (not the Web API Key) seen in the *Cloud Messaging* Tab in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com).

Comment: `When using FCM, you should always make use of the Server Key (not the Web API Key) seen in the Cloud Messaging Tab in your Firebase Console.` - This saved our time....